# Generate csv file in UNIX server using ODI 12c

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I developed two ODI packages in Dev environment to generate a csv file in  UNIX Dev server and UNIX Sandbox server. Both ODI scenarios run successfully but the csv file is generated in UNIX Dev server but not in Sandbox server. If the dev ODI is not recognizing the Sandbox UNIX server, shouldn't it have thrown error while executing the scenario? Do I need to do any topology configurations for this? Experts, please help!

Comment: It depends a bit on your configuration. Do you have an agent on each of these servers? If so make sure the path you are creating the file exists on Sandbox server. Also check the OS user running the agent has write privilege into the folder. In the physical topology in the JDBC tab of your data server definition you can provide a ERR_FILE_PATH parameter that will write 2 files for errors and bad records. You should be able to find out more with this.

Comment: Thanks Jerome for your reply! I checked all what you said and looks like it is all good between the ODI and the Sandbox UNIX server. I also tried creating a physical schema, logical schema and context mapping for the Sandbox UNIX server path, still the scenario is running without error but the file is not in the path. Is there any way, I can mention the UNIX server name in the topology configurations? I don't see such thing done anywhere in my current project though

Comment: Your Sandbox agent is supposed to be on the Sandbox server so it's always writing locally. If the landing location is not local, you would need to first write locally then use OdiScp tool to copy it over. Or (s)FTP. Or use a shared folder.